# Printing text in color in a command window

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, python-2.7, ctypes

I am writing a simple python function to print the text in color on a windows computer in a command window.
When I print two text on the same line, the first text takes the color of the second one. This is happening in python 3.7, but in python 2.7, the two texts can be printed in two different colors on the same line. Below is my code:

```
#Python3 code

from ctypes import *

def PrintInColor(text, color):
    # The color is an int and text is simply passed through
    windll.Kernel32.GetStdHandle.restype = c_ulong
    h = windll.Kernel32.GetStdHandle(c_ulong(0xfffffff5))
    x = windll.Kernel32.SetConsoleTextAttribute(h, color)
    print(text, end=' ')

def printing():
    PrintInColor("FAIL", 0xC) #Red  
    PrintInColor("PASS", 0xA) #Green

printing()
```

Python 2 code

```
from ctypes import *

def PrintInColor(text, color):
    # The color is an int and text is simply passed through
    windll.Kernel32.GetStdHandle.restype = c_ulong
    h = windll.Kernel32.GetStdHandle(c_ulong(0xfffffff5))
    x = windll.Kernel32.SetConsoleTextAttribute(h, color)
    print text,

def printing():
    PrintInColor("FAIL", 0xC) #Red  
    PrintInColor("PASS", 0xA) #Green

printing()
```

From the below screenshot, the "FAIL" and "PASS" are all in green, FAIL should be in red and PASS in green.

[image]

Comment: did you test modules like [colorama](https://github.com/tartley/colorama), [blessings](https://github.com/erikrose/blessings) or similar ?

Comment: `print(text, end=' ')` causes a `SyntaxError` in Python 2.

Comment: for python 2  do ```print text, end=' '```

Comment: Same error. Please post some real code. -1 til then.

Comment: @CristiFati , the code that I posted was for Python 3, I added the code for python 2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the `flush` keyword argument for [`print`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print).

```py
    print(text, end=' ', flush=True)
```

[image]

---

Besides that, here's my test script:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import ctypes

STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE = -11

def raise_if_0(result, func, arguments):
    if result == 0:
        raise Winerror()

_k32 = ctypes.WinDLL('kernel32', use_last_error=True)
_GetStdHandle = _k32.GetStdHandle
_GetStdHandle.restype = ctypes.c_void_p
_GetStdHandle.argtypes = [ctypes.c_void_p]
_SetConsoleTextAttribute = _k32.SetConsoleTextAttribute
_SetConsoleTextAttribute.restype = ctypes.c_bool
_SetConsoleTextAttribute.argtypes = [ctypes.c_void_p, ctypes.c_uint16]
_SetConsoleTextAttribute.errcheck = raise_if_0



def PrintInColor(text, color):
    # The color is an int and text is simply passed through
    hout = _GetStdHandle(ctypes.c_void_p(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE))
    x = _SetConsoleTextAttribute(hout, color)
    print(text, end=' ', flush=True)

def printing():
    PrintInColor("FAIL", 0xC) #Red  
    PrintInColor("PASS", 0xA) #Green

printing()
```

A few things to notice:

- Use of `use_last_error`passed to [`ctypes.WinDLL`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#ctypes.WinDLL)
- Use of [`argtypes`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#ctypes._FuncPtr.argtypes), [`restype`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#ctypes._FuncPtr.restype) and [`errcheck`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#ctypes._FuncPtr.errcheck)